# set @SafeHtml annontation on all class properties automatically

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

Is there any possibility to apply `@SafeHtml` annotation or another alternative for all class `String` type properties instead of set it for each property manually

```
public class user{

@SafeHtml(whitelistType = WhiteListType.NONE)
private String firstName;
....
@SafeHtml(whitelistType = WhiteListType.NONE)
private String lastName;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool "find" `CTRL + F` from Notepad++.

For example:

[image]

You need to select the directory.

The output will be: `@SafeHtml(whitelistType = WhiteListType.NONE) private String firstName;`

... and it is the same that:

```
@SafeHtml(whitelistType = WhiteListType.NONE)
private String firstName;
```

Comment: thank's but im not looking for this kind of solution

Comment: Yes, I imagined it. Could you explain your kind of solution to do it, what do you expect?

Comment: im looking for interceptor that execute a function before saving/updating an entity in database, so this function uppercase text for each class property for example

Comment: Well I guess you are looking for the SaveOrUpdateEventListener interface: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/event/SaveOrUpdateEventListener.html

Comment: thank's there is many solution : hiubernateValidatorInterceptiors, listeners or PreUpdate and PrePersist function :)